# Global variables and context in openerp

Tags: odoo

What I need to do is access values of the columns in a certain module before it's saved.

For example, if we have a module defined like this:

```
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Department Name', size=64, required=True),
    'complete_name': fields.function(_dept_name_get_fnc, type="char", string='Name'),
    'parent_id': fields.many2one('hr.department', 'Parent Department', select=True),
    'child_ids': fields.one2many('hr.department', 'parent_id', 'Child Departments'),
    'note': fields.text('Note'),
}
```

All those columns are represented by controls such as textbox, combobox, checkbox, etc.

When we open the form view in the create mode, a new record is being created but not saved and won't take an id in the database until we click (save).

The question is how to access the values of those fields (controls) before they are saved and before the current record takes a new id.

I know about self.browse and self.search but they need an ID which is not available because the record is not saved yet.

Also, can we assign a global variable that could be accessed from any class in the module (a session variable in web-development terms)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access this field than you need to override the create method of orm. For Example:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    name = vals.get('name')
    complete_name = vals.get('complete_name') # like all others field if one2many field comes than this field access using for loop.

    vals.update({'your_field_name': your_value_what_you_want_to_update_before_creating})
    #vals.update({'name': 'Your Good Name'})

    return super(your_class_name, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)

def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    print "\n\n\nCurrent Values =>", vals
    name = vals.get('name')
    print "\nCurrent Name => ", name
    complete_name = vals.get('complete_name') # like all others field if one2many field comes than this field access using for loop.

    #do all calculation as you want and store in local variable and that variable pass as a value. for example.  
    name = 'Your Good Name'
    vals.update({'name': name})

    print "\n\nUpdated Values => ", vals 

    return super(your_class_name, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear enough, what I need is to access the fields and perhaps make some calculations during runtime not just when I click save. I believe that overriding the create method would work only at the moment I click (Save) and the record starts its journey to the database.

Comment: Create method calls only one time and you want to do some calculation than we can override write method. and Same do as create method code will work. And i update my answer with write method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but isn't there anyway to read the values of the fields before we go to the database? something like (getElementByID) in javascript?

Comment: yes, this is same as getElementByID in javascrip. What you want to read field than you can access by vals.get('field_name'). If your field is one2many or many2many than it will be using loop.

Comment: I tried to use vals in a method but this variable is defined only in create and write methods, otherwise it has to be passed to the method from another method. Would you give an example please?

Comment: it's not only way to do so. For example make a one button and pass value in context. In Button method you get value like context.get('field_name').

Answer (score 0):

Better override create method, and use the way you want. Try this in you object, Its an example,

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    if vals.get('name','/')=='/':
        vals['name'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'sale.order') or '/'
    return super(sale_order, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

likewise you can do your changes from here itself, see the value of "vals" and "context",
this would be helpful to you.